# Не маркированный список складывается в линию на мобильном

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так в верстке? На десктопе список выглядит как надо, строчки располагаются друг под другом, но на мобильном список схлапывается в одну линию, а ссылки в кучу. Что не хватает в коде?

```css
ul.block {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul.block li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.block img {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>Название блока</div>
  <ul class="block">
    <li>
      <img src="" align="left"><a class="company_soc" href=""> - пояснение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" align="left"><a class="company_soc" href=""> - пояснение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" align="left"><a class="company_soc" href=""> - пояснение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" align="left"><a class="company_soc" href=""> - пояснение</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="" align="left"><a class="company_soc" href=""> - пояснение</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: может, потому что у Вас div закрывается в самом начале после заголовка, а потом закрывается ещё раз внизу?

Comment: на каком мобильном, с каким разрешением, в каком браузере? пробовал эмулировать разные, ничего не схлопывается

Comment: @humster_spb нет, там нормально все открывается и закрывается) Это я случайно его в примере не включила

Comment: @yolosora Схлапывается на Сафари, но и на десктопе это видно, когда уменьшаешь окно меньше 420px. Не понимаю совершенно, что именно дает этот эффект.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С тем кодом, который вы предоставляете схлопывание в одну линию невозможно. Скорее всего у вас стоит медиа запрос для малых экранов. Чтобы проверить это откройте вашу страницу на десктопе, для примера браузером `Chrome`. Откройте дев тулс, выберете просмотр на мобильном, выделите меню, которое показывается не верно и посмотрите какие стили там видны. Так же вы увидите где прописан этот медиа запрос, зайдите у себя в тот файл и исправьте его так, как вам надо.

**UPD**: то есть вы должны будете увидеть подобную картину:

[image: Скрин]

Посмотрите все стили у `ul`, посмотрите все стили у `li`. Возможно нужно прокрутить, чтобы увидеть медиа, а может они вообще с помощью `js` проставляются, а может у вас грузится мобильная версия и там все `li` - блочные. А может, у вас настолько длинные названия элементов списка, и они просто не влезли в экран. А может родителю прописался флексбокс.

С тем кодом, который вы предоставили, увы больше ничем не помочь.

Comment: Я так и делала. Удалила все правила, которые могут влиять на этот блок, он все равно схлапывается. Буду смотреть дальше. Может что-то пропускаю..

Comment: Обновила ответ, посмотрите

Comment: спасибо за своевременное напоминание пересмотреть код. Действительно нашла свойство из-за которого список схлапывался в линию